# Weighting sum of losses

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

Is it true that loss should be weighted according to loss value? i.e. for example we have `loss = loss_a * loss_a_weight + loss_b * loss_b_weight` and at some point `loss_a = 98.3` and `loss_b = 0.2`, so is it true to make losses equally contributing we should use weight `loss_a_weight=1.0` and `loss_b_weight = loss_a / loss_b`? is it good idea to make `loss_b_weight` dynamic based on `loss_a, loss_b` at current step?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It sounds like you might be interested in reading about Pareto optimization.

Comment: @Sycorax Actually it's a general question, but this sum of weighted losses are common in many tasks related to computer vision + deep learning, for example eq.3 from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your proposal to assign $w_a=1$ and $w_b =\frac{L_a}{L_b} $ means that $L_b$ plays no role in the optimization. Instead of increasing the importance of $L_b$, the resulting loss depends only on $L_a$. Assuming $L_b > 0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
L &= w_a L_a + w_b L_b \\
&= L_a + \frac{L_a}{L_b}L_b \\
&= L_a + L_a \\
&= 2 L_a
\end{align}
$$

If you want to give $L_b$ more than zero weight, you'll have to use a different scheme.